# How to update a section of an NSView without redrawing the whole view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics, nsview

I have a NSView where I draw thousands of NSBezierPaths. I would like to highlight (change fill color) the a selected one on mousemoved event. At the moment I use in mouseMoved function the following command:

```
     [self setsetNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

that force a call to drawRect to redraw **every** path. I would like to redraw only the selected one. 
I tried to use addClip in drawRect function:

```
      NSBezierPath * path = ... //builds the path here
      [path addClip];
      [path fill];
```

but it seems that drawRect destroys all the other previously drawn paths and redraws only the one clipped.

Is it possible NOT to invalidate all the view when calling drawRect? I mean just to incrementally overwrite what was on the view before?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:…]`. Pass the NSRect you want invalidated, and that will be the area passed to the `drawRect:` call.

Inside `drawRect:`, check the area that was passed in and only perform the drawing necessary inside of that rectangle.

Also, you might want to look into using `NSTrackingArea` instead of `mouseMoved:` – these allow you to set up specific rectangles to trigger updates for.

Comment: Hi,
ok, I can pass something like: [self setNeedsDisplayInRect: [path bounds]]... even if it is not very comfortable because I do not know how many paths there are on that NSRect... but I can try to rethink the function.

Instead it is not very clear how I can exploit NSTrackingArea. At the moment I have already a trackingarea that covers the whole NSView, but I thought that the events generated are still sent to the mouseMoved function, aren't they?
Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Your `mouseMoved:` method will be triggered with an `NSEvent` instance, and you send the event the `-trackingArea` message to get a reference to the `NSTrackingArea` instance which triggered it, and then ask it for the rect.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved in a faster way, as I do not know a priori which paths are present in a rectangle I want to avoid a loop through all the paths. Fortunately my paths do not change often, so I can cache all the paths in a NSImage. On mouseMoved event I set:

```
RefreshAfterMouseMoved = YES;
```

and in drawRect function I put something like:

```
if (RefreshAfterMouseMoved) {       
    [cacheImage drawAtPoint:zero fromRect:viewRect operation:1 
                       fraction:(CGFloat)1.0];
        //redraw only the hilighted path
}
else{
    if (cacheImage) [cacheImage release];   
    cacheImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: [self bounds].size ];
    [cacheImage lockFocus];
    // draw everything here
    [cacheImage unlockFocus];
    [cacheImage drawAtPoint:zero fromRect:viewRect operation:1 
                   fraction:(CGFloat)1.0];
}
```

This method can be combined with the above setNeedsDisplayInRect method putting in mousedMoved function:

```
   NSRect a, b, ab;
   a = [oldpath bounds];
   b = [newpath bounds];
   ab = NSUnionRect(a,b);
   RefreshAfterMouseMoved = YES;
   [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:ab];
```